# Best practices: How to improve this code that sums container values?

Tags: c++, stl

I am writing a simple function that iterates over the numbers in a container and computes some summarizing value (the entropy in this case).

I want to write it as generic as possible, so that it works with different containers (`vector`, `set`, ...) over different value types (`double`, `float`, ...), so I'm doing this:

```
template<class Iterator>
typename Iterator::value_type Entropy(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
  typedef typename Iterator::value_type Value;
  Value result = Value(); // assignment needed?
  for (Iterator it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
    result -= *it * log(*it);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I'm interested in what this code would look like according to all best practices. In other words, what exactly would an STL implementation of this little function look like?

Comment: The set of "all best practices" is so conflicting the code would never get written.  What do you really mean?

Comment: I'm just curious how the implementers of the STL would have written this. I'd like to learn how to write code that is as concise and generic as the STL code itself ...

Answer (score 4):

look into std::transform and std::accumulate

Comment: Interesting, why does the source code for transform (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01056_source.html#l00116) use an additional template parameter for the value type, instead of just using the `Iterator::value_type`, like I did?

Comment: @user: You are linking to `accumulate`. You can choose an initial value (e.g when multiplying all values, 1 would be good), and the result type does not have to be the same as `Iter::value_type`.

Comment: because you might want another result type, e.g. when caculating the mean from a list of integers, you still want a real valued result.

Answer (score 4):

```
template < typename T1, typename T2 >
T1 entropy_sum(T1 sum_so_far, T2 number)
{
  return sum_so_far - static_cast<T1>(number) * log(static_cast<T1>(number));
}
double entropy = std::accumulate(set.begin(), set.end(), 0.0, &entropy_sum<double, set_type::value_type>);
```

You method is OK except for the fact that `Value()` might not be a legal statement.

Edited to reflect comment.

Comment: But `log` is also defined for `float` and `long double`, so I'd like to allow those types too.

Comment: Then parameterize the return and first arg as well.  You'll also need to do specific casting in that case otherwise the log picked for integer types may not be what you want.

Answer (score 4):

In C++0x the following lambda version can be used:

```
template<class Iterator>
typename Iterator::value_type Entropy(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
  typedef typename Iterator::value_type Value;
  return accumulate(begin, end, Value(), 
      [] (Value i, Value j)-> Value { return i - j * log(j); });  
}
```

Comment: Why [&] when you don't use any non-local variables (i.e. begin, end)?

Comment: You're right @Fred, I confess I still have my L-plates on in this area.  Edited, thanks.  Part of a private quest to understand lambda syntax better.

Comment: we're all on this quest I think, apart from litb who obviously mastered it years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator_traits/) for this:

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type Value;
```

This allows Iterator to be a pointer.